# WPF 3.5 Easing Functions for Animations?

Tags: wpf, animation, easing-functions

I know that there are some easing functions for silverlight and WPF 4.0 coming out.

But I really need some for my own project, and I cant seem to find any on the net (not for WPF 4.0)

Does anyone know any implementations or perhaps ports from Silverlight that I could use?

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found these:

http://code.google.com/p/wpf-animation/

If anyone knows of any better/different please let me know :)